# Truncated Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in L^2[0,2\pi]$. Suppose that $\exists k\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. the Fourier coefficients $a_n,b_n$ of $f$ vanish for $n\geq k$. In this situation, can we conclude that $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}(a_n\cos nx+b_n\sin nx)$ for a.e. $x\in[0,2\pi]$? It seems that we cannot use the Fejer theorem without assuming continuity. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Lebesgue theorem shows that $\sigma_n(f) \to f$ at every Lebesgue point (hence ae for $f \in L^1$) - see here for the definition of Lebesgue points https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_point

Comment: Thank you. But I don't see any relation between Lebesgue pts and $k$.

Comment: $\sigma_n(f)$ is the Feijer series of $f$ so it is a trigonometric polynomial converging to $\frac{1}{2}a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}(a_n\cos nx+b_n\sin nx)$ on one hand (by its definition and $a_n,b_n =0, n \ge k$) and also converging ae to $f$ by Lebesgue theorem, so $f$ must be a trigonometric polynomial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(S_j)$ be the sequence of partial sums of the Fourier series. Then $S_j \to f$ in $L^{2}$. Hence there is a subsequence which converges to $f$ almost everywhere. But $S_j =\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k-1}(a_n\cos(nx)+b_n \sin (nx))$ for all $j$ sufficiently large. Hence $f =\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k-1}(a_n\cos(nx)+b_n \sin (nx))$ almost everywhere.